# Loading different pages with dynamic tabs and codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

so i have 2 different pages named 'umroh' and 'hajj'. i linked both of them with something like

```
<div class="row">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li style="background:white;">
            <a href="#">
                <h4>Umroh</h4>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="<?=base_url().'haji';?>"><h4>Hajj</h4>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

both of them are in different folder too. now i need them to be connected using dynamic tabs and maybe using js/ jsquery/ ajax
i've read some examples online but mostly the contents that needed are in the same folder
i'm very new to ajax and javascript, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: *i've read some examples online but mostly the contents that needed are in the same folder*, can you share the example you have seen? most likely you will need to change url path to load files on "different folder." though, i had doubts about your codeigniter tag, you might be subject to flags later.

Comment: i've read from : https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp and also from : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613780/load-page-under-tab-dynamically
oh okay, should i just empty it then?